# How to format an Intel Optane 905P SSD as a DAX volume?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have an Intel Optane 905P SSD installed under Windows 10 Home and formatted as and ordinary NTFS volume.

I would like to format this device as a DAX volume. The following command:

```
`format f: /DAX /Q`
```

gives me the following error:

```
`The device is not DAX capable.  Try formatting without DAX support.`
```

Well, the device is supposed to be DAX capable.

I installed all relevant drivers from Intel:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/consumer-ssds/optane-ssd-9-series/optane-ssd-905p-series/905p-960gb-aic-20nm.html

Not sure what else I need to do in order to be able to create a DAX volume. Google does not help. Can anyone, with more storage class memory experience enlighten me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DAX  (direct access persistent memory) is a function available only to the PMem type of non-volatile RAM (NVDIMM) . The Optane SSDs are not this kind of memory, thus aren't DAX compatible nor capable.

You need Intel Optane DC persistent memory to use DAX:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/deploy-pmem